# App Engine Objectify not creating index on base class field

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

Let's say I have a simple Entity hierarchy setup where a base (abstract) class has common fields:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Base {
    @Id
    Long  mId;

    @Index
    Long  mVal;
}
```

Now I have a subclass (both in Java and in Objectify):

```
@Subclass(index=true)
public class Concrete extends Base {
    @Index  mOtherVal;
}
```

When `Concrete` is saved, it is properly creating the entries in the datastore for all of the fields (`mId`, `mVal` and `mOtherVal`).  However, if I attempt to run a query against `Concrete` entries with a filter on `mVal`, app engine is complaining that there is no index:

```
List<Concrete> result = 
    OfyService.ofy().load().type(Concrete.class).filter("mVal > ", 10).list();
```

I see an exception log like this:

`com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: cause={0}
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
    <datastore-index kind="Post" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="^i" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="mVal" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>`

I have not created a `datastore-indexes.xml` intentionally, as the Objectify docs state that indexes on fields are created on the fly.  So my question: is this a known limitation of Objectify, or have I done something incorrectly?

Comment: To my knowledge, it should be possible but I can see why a composite index is required.  Because you're filtering only the subclass (held in the `^i` property), the query needs a composite index for the class information (`^i`) and `mVal`.  My guess is that the Objectify docs are referring to single property indexes, but I'll defer to _stickfigure_ on that!

Comment: Thanks, that was my concern.  The docs are a bit vague with regards to this type of composite index.  I'll try injecting the composite in the `datastore-indexes.xml` and see if it changes the behavior.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer you don't necessarly need to add it yourself. A good idea to make sure all indexes you need is to run all your queries on your devserver. That'll populate "datastore-indexes.xml" itself (see my full answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424157/how-to-build-datastore-indexes-php-gae/28480515#28480515

Comment: Thanks @Patrice, appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer very welcome :) composite indexes are not easy to adapt to. I prefer to not take any chances, run my devserver to create everything, and then looking in datastore-indexes.xml and remove the super big indices that I don't need to be fast (to make use of the zig-zag merge)

Comment: Adding the composite index fixed it, I'm now seeing good results.  I hadn't bothered with the devserver datastore setup but I may need to roll over to that for some of my testing in order to avoid this type of hiccup.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have probably figured out from the comments on the question, you need a multiproperty index in `datastore-indexes.xml`.

I hope it's fairly obvious why this is necessary - you are requesting a query where `mVal` is constrained with an inequality and the discriminator index (implemented by Objectify as a property `^i`) includes a specific value. If you want to be a little more clever, you can query for `ofy().load().type(Base.class).filter("mVal > ", 10)` and you won't need the extra index because the simple single-property index suffices.

Multiproperty indexes (maintained by GAE in datastore-indexes.xml) are very different from the single property indexes maintained by Objectify. This is explained at length in the GAE docs.

Comment: Yes, with everyone's help, the docs and experimentation I was able to come to the same conclusion.  I had an inkling this was going to be the case, but wasn't positive as the docs were a bit vague on it.  It makes perfect sense with how Objectify handles the inheritance, I was just hoping there was some magic in there I was missing.  Thanks for the feedback!