# GAE Index error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The code works well on local host

but when I upload it to GAE, I keep getting an error:

```
NeedIndexError: no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
- kind: DataModel
  properties:
  - name: __key__
    direction: desc
```

I searched that the error is caused by not updated index, so I waited 2 days.
But still getting the error.

I suspect that I used three different orders:

```
DataModel.query(DataModel.key <= ndb.Key('DataModel',continuity_checked_id)).order(
                -DataModel.key).fetch(2001)

DataModel.query().order(-DataModel.date, -DataModel.times)

DataModel.query(DataModel.key >= ndb.Key("DataModel", last_checked_DataModel)).order(DataModel.key).fetch()
```

How can I solve the problem??

Comment: is the suggested index in your datastore-index.xml?

Comment: The system doesn't generate your indexes if you don't tell them to. You need to either : a) run the query on devserver so it can generate the index itself to be there when you push it, or b) add that specific index to your file so it goes in the system when it's pushed

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build datastore indexes (PHP GAE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424157/how-to-build-datastore-indexes-php-gae)

Comment: ... did you test THAT query in your dev and THEN deployed? or do you have a deployed version and you're trying devserver now, without changing what's deployed after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you need to create an index for the query you are attempting to run. For reference refer too: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/indexconfig

```
indexes:

- kind: DataModel
  properties:
  - name: __key__
    direction: desc
```