# How to create google datastore composite indices via REST API?

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to change the order of my results but I keep getting an error saying `You need an index to execute this query.`

In my console, I doesn't say that any indices exist, but I set most of the indexed options to true.

I know in Java, I can create indices that relate to multiple properties either ascending or descending, how do I do this with the REST API?

Following the [REST API docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/) for Google Datastore, my entities are created like this:

```
{
  "mode": "TRANSACTIONAL",
  "transaction": "Eb2wksWfYDjkGkkABRmGMQ_vKGijwNwm-tbxAbUPRt8N2RaUCynjSbGT7jFQw3pgaDCT7U0drs3RTPLSIN8TQikdqkdl7pLm2rkMqORmKlO_I_dp",
  "mutation": {
    "insertAutoId": [
      {
        "key": {
          "path": [
            {
              "kind": "Attendance"
            }
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "section": {
            "indexed": true,
            "stringValue": "Venturers"
          },
          "date": {
            "dateTimeValue": "2015-01-16T00:00:00+00:00",
            "indexed": true
          },
          "attendee": {
            "indexed": true,
            "keyValue": {
              "path": [
                {
                  "id": "5659313586569216",
                  "kind": "Attendee"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "presence": {
            "indexed": false,
            "integerValue": 0
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I am trying to query like this:

```
{
  "gqlQuery": {
    "allowLiteral": true,
    "queryString": "SELECT * FROM Attendance WHERE section = @section ORDER BY date ASC",
    "nameArgs": [
      {
        "name": "section",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "Venturers"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "FAILED_PRECONDITION",
        "message": "no matching index found.",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "If-Match"
      }
    ],
    "code": 412,
    "message": "no matching index found."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

You can't make a composite index directly through the REST API.  You must go through php app engine.

[How to build datastore indexes (PHP GAE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424157/how-to-build-datastore-indexes-php-gae)

Comment: how you know his appengine is php?

Comment: @ZigMandel 'cause who else would know what he's using? :)